# plotting & formatting seaborn chart from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe `al_df` that contains the population of Alabama from a recent US census. I created a cumulative function that I plot using `seaborn`, resulting in this chart:

[image: CDF for the population of Alabama]

The code that relates to the plotting is this:

```
figure(num=None, figsize=(20, 10))

plt.title('Cumulative Distribution Function for ALABAMA population')
plt.xlabel('City')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
#sns.set_style("whitegrid", {"ytick.major.size": "0.1",})
plt.plot(al_df.pop_cum_perc)
```

My questions are:
1) How can I change the ticks, so the yaxis shows a grid line every 0.1 units instead of the default 0.2 shown?
2) How can I change the x axis to show the actual names of the city, plotted vertically, instead of the "rank" of the city (from the Pandas index)? (there are over 300 names, so they are not going to fit well horizontally).

Comment: Where does plt come from?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib, so you can access elements of a seaborn chart using import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, just like in the example above

Comment: Sorry! There isn't any import line in your code, so I was wondering how you imported plt. Did you import it as matplotlib.plt or seaborn.plt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, and not been able to find a "native" Seaborn solution, I came up with the code below, partially based on @Pablo Reyes and @CT Zhu suggestions, and using matplotlib functions:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import *
figure(num=None, figsize=(20, 10))

plt.title('Cumulative Distribution Function for ALABAMA population')
plt.xlabel('City')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.plot(al_df.pop_cum_perc)

#set the tick size of y axis
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))

#set the labels of y axis and text orientation
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation =90)
```

The solution introduced a new element "labels" which I had to specify before the plot, as a new Python list created from my Pandas dataframe:

```
labels = al_df.NAME.values[:]
```

Producing the following chart:
[image]

This requires some tweaking, since specifying a display of every city in the pandas data frame, like this:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
```

Produces a chart impossible to read (displaying only x axis):
[image]

Comment: I try your method for my dataframe, but it doesn't work, maybe I make smth wrong? I have dataframe with three columns, one is the Names of students, and  two others are the number of false and true answers for every student. So I would like visualize repartition of answers per student. But instead of picture like yours, I have only empty figure with first student as labels and without any curve. why could it happen?

Comment: my script looks like ```
plt.plot(df.FALSE_ANSWER)

#set the tick size of y axis
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
labels = df.name_of_student[:]
#set the labels of y axis and text orientation
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation =90) ```

Comment: @very_young I think a cumulative chart would not work for your data (at least, it does not make sense to me). Why don't you post a new question referencing this answer? In that way, you could get a few quality answers from other people, including the one I'll post for you. Txs.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1) ,add:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,1+0.1,0.1))
```

Question 2), I found this in the matplotlib gallery:
[ticks_and_spines example code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `matplotlib` way would be to use `MutlipLocator`. The second one is also straight forward

```
from matplotlib.ticker import *
plt.plot(range(10))
ax=plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
plt.xticks(range(10), list('ABCDEFGHIJ'), rotation=90) #would be range(3xx), List_of_city_names, rotation=90
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]