# how to label axis with all the row names from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I have the dataframe that contains about 430 rows:

```
     name         Right_Answers  Wrong_Answers
    Alice Ji      7                6
    Eleonora LI   2                5
    Mike The      6                5
    Helen Wo      5                3
```

for visualize the number of right (red) and wrong (blue) answers I'm using the matplotlib library with following functions:

```
g=df.plot(x='name', color=['b','r'], figsize=(100,50))  
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
labels = df.name.values[:]
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
```

but I have always only 8 names as labels on X axis, instead of 430 (rotated vertically, so there are enough of space for much more row names)! why it happens? I thought this method put all the row names on axis `labels = df.name.values[:]` but apparently not. 
do you know other solution for this problem? 
I'm ready to try another libraries as seaborn or ggplot, even if I haven't found them very comfortable for dataframe compared with matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe, you can use Pandas' built-in plotting methods, e.g.:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', color=['red', 'blue'])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works when I precise ```kind='bar``` , but it's strange for me why when I don't precise this argument and I want just line and not bar plot, the same pandas plotting functions don't put all the row names as labels on the axis? (but still plot beautiful line plot)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (iPython notebook):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%pylab inline
mydata = [{'Name':'John', 'TRUE_ANSWER': 75, 'FALSE_ANSWER':25},
          {'Name':'Mike', 'TRUE_ANSWER': 60, 'FALSE_ANSWER':40},]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
columns = ['Name','TRUE_ANSWER', 'FALSE_ANSWER']
df = df[columns]
df.index=df["Name"]
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

I think that trying to do the cumulative chart chart you asked me about in question [plotting & formatting seaborn chart from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160730/plotting-formatting-seaborn-chart-from-pandas-dataframe/23201969?noredirect=1#comment55290783_23201969) will not work with your set. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I upvote your answer, but I marked the first one as correct, cause of works for me, and it seems to be shorter and though more beautiful! I don't want cumulative chart but just line chart, and it turns out that without precising the ```kind='bar'``` it doesn't plot all the names as labels of x axis, and just 8 from 430. but it works well with  ```kind='bar'``` , still I'm looking for solution to plot line chart, and have all the row names as labels of X axe